Build-tool 34.0.0 is missing AAPT
I have this known problem with android.
Installed Build Tools revision 34.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.
to fix it I have done what stackoverflow was suggesting. rename d8.bat to dx.bat in AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\34.0.0 and also the lib folder.
I also updated gradle to 8.7.
Both have not fixed the issue, I restarted everything, still have the same error.
Is there something else to check?
Why does this issue still exist ond a fresh installation decades after first occurance?

same problem here

I have also tried renaming the files and it did not help. What now helped was just deleting the build-tool 34.0.0, and when I made a new build, it got installed automatically. The build again failed, but the next build succeeded.
